# How to hack a turret in Bioshock?

Tags: bioshock

I've found that most cameras can be hacked by sneaking another them and hacking from below. Also the flying helicopters can be hacked if they are protecting an enemy which is killed.

What I can't work out is how to directly hack a turret. It's difficult to get close to them without suffering severe health loss.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [Electro Bolt](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Electro_Bolt) plasmid on them; this will shut the turret temporarily for enough time to get close enough.

Comment: Looks like [Winter Blast](http://bioshock.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_Blast) is similarly effective.

Comment: This also works on security bots that are attacking you.

Comment: Winter blast will also decrease the speed of the fluid.